Question regarding global thresholding algorithm for images
I am trying to mathematically prove that for an initial choice of threshold To, if we compute the successive thresholds as average of foreground and background means, the thresholds will follow a non-decreasing or non-increasing trend, i.e. if

To <= T1

, we will always have

Tn+1 <= Tn

.
I tried to prove this using the computed means, asserting that mean of background region will be always less than threshold and that of foreground more than the threshold, but cannot generalize the

Tn+1 <= Tn

case.
Further, I am looking to determine the convergence criteria.

Just to clarify, the threshold $T_0$ determines which pixels are in the foreground and which pixels are in the background, correct? That is, if $P \geq T_0$ for some pixel $P$ in the image, then $P$ is a foreground pixel, and $P$ is a background pixel otherwise, correct?

The algorithm you describe is k-means clustering with k=2 on one-dimensional data. So you’re asking how to prove that k-means clustering always converges. There is a proof for example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188087/186531

Yes, that is correct @mhdadk
